# $request->files->all() is always empty

Tags: php, symfony, postman

I'm testing my API with POSTMAN and when I try to send any file the content of $request->files->all() is always empty.

$request->server->parameters["CONTENT_LENGTH"] seems to change depending on the file size. But I don't find a way to reach the file content.

Tried also with $_FILES, but the same result.

I even did a var_dump($_FILES); in my app_dev.php directly before reaching anything else from Symfony's framework.

My php.ini seems to be alright:
file_uploads: on
upload_max_filesize: more than enough
post_max_size: more than enough

In POSTMAN I tried both ways of sending a file: binary and form-data file.

A POSTMAN code example looks like this using form-data:

```
PUT /retain_inspecciones/web/app_dev.php/api/planningfiles/6?files=true HTTP/1.1
Host: symfony.dev
symfonytoken: Bearer my-token
Cache-Control: no-cache
Postman-Token: 9c9cd91a-99f2-57ab-a290-966074b219f3
Content-Type: multipart/form-data; boundary=----WebKitFormBoundary7MA4YWxkTrZu0gW

------WebKitFormBoundary7MA4YWxkTrZu0gW
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="fileName"; filename=""
Content-Type: 


------WebKitFormBoundary7MA4YWxkTrZu0gW--
```

I'm not sure of why the part where the file should be is the empty string and Content-Type is empty. But it seems to be the way POSTMAN does so.

Any idea?

Comment: @CBroe I think it doesn't matter on this case, I've captured the request before handling the method. And I've tested them both. Anyway I want to use PUT since I'm updating an entity, not creating one. $_FILES should be present in both POST and PUT method, isn't it? I mean... I want to send more than a file on the request. Is it possible?

Comment: No, $_FILES is for files uploaded via POST only. If you want PUT support, then you have to implement that yourself: http://php.net/manual/en/features.file-upload.put-method.php (unless symfony already does that for you.)

Answer (score 0):

Finally I decided to try curl instead of Postman and it worked on first try.

I don't know how curl differs from POSTMAN when building the request but I'm happy with it.

Comment: Are you doing POST with curl?

Comment: I'm doing this:
curl -X PUT "url" -F "file=@filename" -b "token=token"

Comment: I am having same problem Kynethix can you answer my question?    https://stackoverflow.com/q/44352796/1395965