# Unable to upload file from Wordpress plugin to symfony backend server over the API?

Tags: php, wordpress, api, symfony, image-uploading

My project have two Parts

- wordpress frontend
- Symfony backend

I am trying to calling the API of may backend symfony project from Wordpress plugin to store some data in the backend. all the text data is being saved but when I am trying to send image files they are not being saved in the backend. I know its a tricky business but I am really looking for the solution.

for uploading images we are doing following steps

1. we are temporarily uploading images to our Wordpress upload folder
2. then we are sending those files in our request in calling api
3. symfony backend API is getting the request and uploading the images accordingly

here is my Wordpress front end code and its request variable:

```
$localUploadPath  = dirname(__DIR__).DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR.'uploads';
$randomDir  = Helper::randomDirName();
$uploadedAssets = Files::uploadPassAssets( $localUploadPath , $randomDir );
$request = new Request();
$submitedValues = $request->all();
$request->files($uploadedAssets);
$groupArray = $request->getGroups();

//remote files upload
$remoteFiles = array();
foreach($uploadedAssets as $fieldName => $imageFiles){
    $imageWithPath = $localUploadPath.'/'.$randomDir.'/'.$imageFiles; 
    $remoteFiles[$fieldName.'File'] = '@'.realpath($imageWithPath);
}
$client = new ClientApi(PASSBUILDER_ADDPASS_UPLOAD_URL);
$client->setFiles($remoteFiles);
$uploadResponse = $client->getResponse();
$this->rrmdir($localUploadPath.'/'.$randomDir);
```

request for the api is:

```
{ ["appearance_logoNameFile"]=> string(149) "@/home/public_html/ads/wp-content/plugins/passbook-app/uploads/4e1020ee2b0dda294c746b5bb5acc0bd/26f27e532c874b63dca651dec4553b20ca237a44.png" ["appearance_eventTicketStripFile"]=> string(149) "@/home/public_html/ads/wp-content/plugins/passbook-app/uploads/4e1020ee2b0dda294c746b5bb5acc0bd/7354f12e6d185eee8142268b32eea6a055036d35.png" ["generalid"]=> string(32) "4ba11ffe3f2b8a46626632b48b38fcaf" ["pass_id"]=> int(198) ["email"]=> string(17) "sample@unknown.com" }
```

images are physically saved in the Wordpress upload folder and also being sent through api but our backend is not picking up the images and are not uploading them

here is our backend code of symfony:

```
public function createpassuploadAction(Request $request){

    $data = $request->request->all();
    $helper = $this->get('passbook.passhelper');
    $webDir = $helper->webDir;

    $passId = $data['pass_id'];
    $userEmail = $data['email'];
    $generalid = $data['generalid'];

    $filesResult = array();
    $filesBag = $request->files->all();
    foreach ($filesBag as $file){
        $filename = $file->getClientOriginalName();
        $filesResult []=  array(
            'path' => $file->getPathname(),
            'url'  => 'ddd'
        );
        $src    =  $webDir.'/upload/'.$passId.'/';
        $file->move( $src ,$filename );
    }
}
```

For the record this code was perfectly running 2 years ago but it suddenly stoped working:

I am getting this error

```
request.INFO: Matched route "curd.api.pass.create.uploads" (parameters: "_format": "json", "_controller": "Cogilent\PassbookBundle\Controller\ApiController::createpassuploadAction", "_route": "curd.api.pass.create.uploads") [] []
[2017-06-04 04:57:07] security.INFO: Populated SecurityContext with an anonymous Token [] []
```

Comment: Can you show Front-End `form`?

Comment: wordpress front end form?

Comment: yes, front end form

Comment: Can you try just `foreach ($request->files as $file){` ?

Comment: nothing happened . filebag is still empty . i removed ->all()

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/145943/discussion-between-imanali-mamadiev-and-numerah).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

there was an error at `'@'.realpath($path)` from php 5.5 and above this is used `curl_file_create(realpath($path))` instead of `'@'`. problem solved